# cambiar value de un input con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

Tengo una serie de repeticiones y necesito sacarle los ceros restantes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

probe con este codigo pero no funciona

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[name*="Peso"]').each(function () {
      var repeticion = $(this).val();
      var repeticionFloat = parseFloat(repeticion);
      var repeticionString = repeticionFloat.toString();
   $(this).val() = repeticionString;
   });
});
```

al hacer console.log a repeticionString trae todo bien sin los ceros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre es bueno apoyarse en la [documentación oficial](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val)

```
   $(this).val() = repeticionString; //Incorrecto

   $(this).val(repeticionString); //correcto
```

aquí tu ejemplo resuelto y funcionando

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('input[name*="Peso"]').each(function () {
      var repeticion = $(this).val();
      var repeticionFloat = parseFloat(repeticion);
      var repeticionString = repeticionFloat.toString();
     console.log(repeticionString)
   $(this).val(repeticionString);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input  name="Peso" value="5.000" type="text">
<input  name="Peso" value="7.000" type="number">
```

Comment: gracias michel! es verdad lo de la documentacion